# Accessing Ember object instances in debugger

Tags: ember.js

In the debugger it's easy enough to get at the class definitions of objects I've created by typing in the `App.ClassName.prototype`. Ok not hugely interesting but still good when you're first feeling around in the "Ember dark". What about instances though? That's really what I want access to.

If my app has moved to the `ActivitiesByDateRoute` and instantiated the `ActivitiesByDateController` then there must be a instance of `ActivitiesByDateController` but what container is it stored in? I thought maybe the Ember debugger (aka, ember-extension) might help me figure this out. I think it should but I'm just not getting it. What does the following indicate to me?

[image]

It appears the instance name is `ember461` but how do I manipulate it in the debugger? I've tried `App.ember461` ... no go. I've tried `App.ActivitiesByDateController.ember461` ... also a no go.

Anyway, you get the gist of my question. Please help, I'm a couple objects short of an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some of easiest way to manipulate an ember model.

Just output one of the model's properties onto the page

```
 {{ someValue }}
```

Bind the value to an input box

```
 {{ input value=someValue }}
```

Log the value of the object when the template is being generated the first time (not when it is changing).

```
 {{ log someValue }}
```

Stop the template while it's being generated so you can view the model.

```
 {{ debugger }}
```

Output the context(s) of the template being built

```
 {{this}}
 {{model}}
 {{controller}}
 {{view}}
```

check out the model in the setupController hook in the route, or even do something as terrible as making the model a global variable that you could view anywhere (I'd just use this for testing/debugging)

```
 App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   setupController: function(controller, model) {
      this._super(controller, model);
      globalSomeModel = model; // I wouldn't recommend polluting the global scope except for testing etc.
   }
 });
```

Trying to grab portions of ember and use/manipulate them outside of the ember run loop can give you unexpected results.

Here's some info I left on another SO post about getting a controller instance outside of the ember run loop though.

```
var controller = Application.__container__.lookup('controller:someCamelCaseName');
```

Some of the previous things I mentioned are viewable in this jsbin http://jsbin.com/efajen/1/edit

Comment: Hi Daniel. You have mentioned:

Output the context(s) of the template being built
 {{this}}
 {{model}}
 {{controller}}
 {{view}}
<br/>Could you explain me it details? How to do it?

Comment: So doing it like that would print them into the dom.  If you'd like them printed in the console you could add the log keyword in front of them, {{log this}},  {{log model}}, {{log controller}}, {{log view}}

Answer (score 2):

Now from the debugger (I mean, the ember-extension plugin), you are able to click on the element, and retrieve it via $E in the console.